# Replacing error redirection to null device in Bash script and create a new file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am attempting to create a new debug installation script from an existing one. The original installation script contains many statements with redirection `>/dev/null 2>&1`. It includes different patterns so I found the regex expression that matches all:

`>{1,2}\s{0,1}\/dev\/null 2>\&1`

I've tested this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ztm2yM/2).

Now I'd like to use this pattern to find and replace all instances of matches with a blank so that in case there are any errors, the output stream will be redirected to the terminal rather to the `null` device. My attempt is:

```sh
sed 's+>{1,2}\s\/dev\/null 2>\&1++g' install.sh > install_debug.sh
```

(I used the `+` instead of `/` as the delimiter to make the string more readable)

But when I grep the output file or just pipe the output without creating the file, `/dev/null` shows that the substitution was not successful:

```sh
sed 's/>{1,2}\s\/dev\/null 2>\&1//g' install.sh | grep "null"
  elif type lsb_release >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    if lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock >> /dev/null 2>&1; then
      sudo apt-get update > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
      sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=falseninteractive apt-get install -y sshpass python-minimal python-pip dbus > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
      sudo apt-get install -y jq > /dev/null 2>&1
      sudo python_for_core_os > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Regex101 is a bad tool for testing this. Sed uses POSIX Regular expressions (either basic or extended), which are significantly different from PCRE ones and the other flavours based on those which Regex101 uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having `\s` in an attempt to match 1 or more between `>` and `/dev`, but the strings can have more or none. Besides, you are not escaping braces in the POSIX BRE pattern, so `sed 's/a{1,2}//'` effectively removes the first `a{1,2}` text, not one or two `a`s. Either use a POSIX ERE (with the `-E` option) to use `a{1,2}`, or escape the braces (i.e. `sed -E 's/a{1,2}//'` = `sed 's/a\{1,2\}//'`).

Also, `&` in the regex pattern is not special, it is only special in the replacement part. Thus, no need escaping it here.
Also, since you used `+` as a delimiter, there is no point escaping `/` chars any longer, replace `\/` with `/`.

Use

```
sed 's+>\{1,2\}[[:space:]]*/dev/null[[:space:]]*2>&1++g' install.sh > install_debug.sh
```

In a GNU `sed` you may surely use `\s` to shorten the pattern:

```
sed -E 's+>{1,2}\s*/dev/null\s*2>&1++g' install.sh > install_debug.sh
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/sLDjA9)

Comment: Some of the strings do have a space after the `>`, some don't. `\s` should be good enough though.

Comment: @JanHudec Yes, in Linux and GNU sed, yes, `\s` is supported. `\s*` or `[[:space:]]*` will match 0 or more whitespace chars.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `{`:

```
$ sed 's#>\{1,2\}\s*/dev/null\s*2>\&1##g' install.txt
  elif type lsb_release ; then
    if lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock ; then
      sudo apt-get update  && \
      sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=falseninteractive apt-get install -y sshpass python-minimal python-pip dbus  && \
      sudo apt-get install -y jq 
      sudo python_for_core_os
```

Comment: Note that I've added `*` to the \s, because you can also write  `>>/dev/null 2>&1` (with lots of spaces between /dev/null and 2>).